# Is there any way to create a non-keyboard user authentication method on Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, authentication, gestures

Now that Windows 8 supports touch screens, is there some third-part software or even an embedded function on Windows 8 that enables a non-keyboard based method (gestural for example) to unlock a password protected user screen?

PS: I'm not talking about a webcam based face recognition, I am thinking on something similar to Android's gestural unlock screen, such as this:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for Windows 8's [Picture Passwords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/b8/signing-in-with-a-picture-password).

You can choose any picture as a background, then record arbitrary gestures and swipes to log in with.

To set it up, go to the Users section of PC Settings and click `Create a picture password`.